# Format dart code as html

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am knocking together a quick debugging view of a backend, as a small set of admin HTML pages (driven by angulardart, but not sure that is critical).

I get back from my XHR call a complex JSON object.  I want to see that on the HTML page formatted nicely.  It doesn't have to be a great implementation, as its just a debug ui, but the goal is to format the object instead of having it be one long string with no newlines.

I looked at trying to pretty print JSON in dart then putting that inside `<pre></pre>` tags, as well as just dumping the dart Map object to string (again, inside or not inside `<pre></pre>` tags.  But not getting to where I want.

Even searched pub for something similar, such as a syntax highlighter that would output html, but didn't find something obvious.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Should be pretty easy. No idea what "not getting to where I want"  means. Please add the code to your question that shows what you tried and explain how the result differs from your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

1. Format your JSON so it's readable
2. Have syntax highlight

For 1 - This can be done with [JsonEncoder with indent](https://api.dartlang.org/1.12.1/dart-convert/JsonEncoder-class.html#id_JsonEncoder-withIndent)

For 2 - You can use the JS lib called [HighlightJs](https://highlightjs.org/) pretty easily by appending your formatted json into a marked-up div. (See highlightjs' doc to see what I mean)

Comment: ```withIndent``` was indeed the piece right in front of my face that I was overlooking.  And HighlightJS looks good! Thanks!